# Can not resolve symbols

Tags: java, android

I am new to android studio and I tried building a program but my code is full of errors and the most common is “can not resolve symbol”. Please what do I do?

Comment: Start with posting the code and errors in your question.

Comment: Post sample of your code. What symbols does not android studio can to resolve?

Comment: Please is there a way I can send pictures? Cos I can’t type them on my phone

Comment: Before begin create you must first read some of the documentation about configuration of Java Arquitecture especially build.gradle configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Clicking the button `Sync Project With Gradle Files` should solve it:

`Tools -> Android -> Sync Project with Gradle Files`

If that fails, try running 'Rebuild project':

`Build -> Rebuild Project`

In the case you are with Android Studio 3.1 or above, you should go to:

`File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files`